# WPF call a method that takes parameters from another dll

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I run a method that takes parameters from another dll?
I import a UserControl from another dll as below but I now either need to call a method within that UserContol or have the ability to set a variable that's contained in that class.

Load UserControl

```
UserControl ucSupportButton = 
new Bootstrapper().LoadUserControl("SC.Support.dll", "Button");
```

Code used in Bootstrapper

```
        public UserControl LoadUserControl(string dllName, string loadType)
    {
        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(applicationRoot, dllName)))
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), dllName));
            Type[] types = asm.GetTypes();

            Type type = types.Where(t => t.Name.Equals(loadType)).FirstOrDefault();

            if (type != null)
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance(type) as UserControl;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: First of all if this is WPF you should not be manipulating UI elements in procedural code That's what XAML is for. Second, you're basically reinventing the wheel, use MEF instead. Microsoft already did that and they know way better than you and me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@HighCore comment seems like the best way to go. Depending on your design, reflection is another option. You can use reflection to get a method or field in that type and then call or set it.

```
var method = paymentObjectInstance.GetType().GetMethod("MethodNameHere",
                  BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

 if (method == null)
 {
    return null;
 }

 var result = method.Invoke(paymentObjectInstance, null);
```

Here's a little [overview of reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx) courtesy of MSDN.